# Regulating Voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, design, buck, boost

I want to rectify my input voltage from AC to DC in the range of 90 vin min to 270 vin max. I was thinking about a buck converter design due to the efficiency however I cannot find one that can take my vin min and vin max. The output voltage desired is 112V DC.

I want my operational current between the range of 15-25 mA DC.  My load is resistive.  And the input voltage is so large because of the operational conditions I want it to be able to perform at.

Please anyone give me some ideas on what i can do to build this circuit using as least components as possible.

Comment: Does it need to be isolated? (Hint..."yes" :)  That will require a transformer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 112VDC? Will it be accessible by an end-user? That will dictate whether or not the supply needs to be isolated.

Comment: thanks for the response however the supply does not have to be isolated.  A transformer could be used in the design however buying a hand wound manufactured part will cost me some money. So looking for alternate ways. And the 112 volts will be used to power a device

Comment: wording was a little confusing on 1st read -- but it seems you want to accept an input anywhere between 90V and 270V AC, and you want a regulated 112V DC out. Suggest title change to something like "regulated output from wide range AC input" and maybe tweaking the 1st sentence for clarity.

Comment: Is this by any chance coming from an AC generator? Just curious if the AC frequency might be subject to variation, too.

Comment: no sir its coming strait from the wall

Answer (score 1):

This is very nearly the description of the first half of a common PC power supply.  You could learn how they work, and then use many of the parts from one.  But they are not simple.

What that part of the circuit does is rectify the input to a high voltage DC.  The resulting DC is then run through a switching supply with isolating transformer to get the desired voltages.  Regulation is done by looking at the output voltage and using it to control the switching system upstream.

It is rather involved, but this may be necessary in order to get the wide input range you seek.

Comment: thanks however i dont think my design will be like a pc power supply...it doesnt have to be isolated and im looking to use as less components as possible to get the desired result. Do you happen to have any links u can share of your idea though i would love to look over them and see what i can use or learn from.

Answer (score 1):

If the supply does not need to be isolated, you can use a power factor correcting (PFC) buck converter. You can use a controller like [TI's UCC29910](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc29910a.pdf) to take care of the control side of things. It will give you a regulated output and draw sinusoidal current from the mains.

If it needs to be isolated, you can still use the PFC buck, but then can introduce a high-efficiency isolated DC/DC converter with 1:1 conversion ratio to provide the isolation (something like a 50% duty cycle half-bridge converter).

If you don't want the overhead of the PFC controller, you should be able to arrange a conventional buck the same way the TI controller does (with the MOSFET in the low side) and use a conventional driver to control it.

Comment: The idea was great and it works.  I actually dug into the website and found a circuit i could use.  Thing is its way to many components and wouldn't fit on the space I have allotted.  Thanks so much though your a genius lol

Comment: Please update your question with how much space you have available, to attract some more attention.

Comment: how would I do that? Sorry kinda new to this

Comment: You may not have enough reputation as of yet. If you work on your profile and do some voting, you'll get reputation and the edit link should work.

Answer (score 0):

I won't lecture you about not isolating your output; we'll just have to assume that no one can touch the device being powered.  Also, since we don't know what it is, we don't know how good the regulation must be.

Note that if you rectify 90V AC, you will get right around 112V DC.  Since you never need to boost the resulting voltage, it only needs to be regulated down.  Hence, a buck converter is one solution.

There are devices designed to regulate the output by switching the input on and off.  I'm not sure what they are called, but ST made the first one I remember seeing.

I could go retro on you, and suggest a gas discharge tube :)  This worked much like a zener diode (and got just as hot).

Try a search for "offline switcher".  I haven't researched them much but they are a lot like what you want, and have an input range that sounds just like your requirements.